# ASP.NET MVC - How to Call dropdown list bind method to another action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Here is my action Method,

```
 public ActionResult getCountry()
    {
        mstrClient objClientList = new mstrClient();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM INV_mstrCountry WHERE CStatus = 'Y'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, con);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        List<mstrClient> CountryList = new List<mstrClient>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            mstrClient objClient = new mstrClient();
            objClient.CountryCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CountryCode"].ToString();
            objClient.Country = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CountryName"].ToString();
            CountryList.Add(objClient);
        }
        objClientList.getCountryList = CountryList;
        return View(objClientList);
    }
```

I want to call above method into this action method,Actualy am learning level in MVC and struggling this thing from past two days.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        mstrClient objClient = new mstrClient();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(objClient);
    }
```

Comment: You only need the list of mstrClient? in that case you can store in a var and use it in your create method

Comment: Hia Ivan-san can ypu plz sent the sample code

Comment: Hi, If you can share the class I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

How to call a DropDownList in your view in MVC. 
First change the method to return a object and not the view:

```
public List<mstrClient> getCountry()
{
    mstrClient objClientList = new mstrClient();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM INV_mstrCountry WHERE CStatus = 'Y'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, con);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    List<mstrClient> CountryList = new List<mstrClient>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        mstrClient objClient = new mstrClient();
        objClient.CountryCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CountryCode"].ToString();
        objClient.Country = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CountryName"].ToString();
        CountryList.Add(objClient);
    }
    return CountryList;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    mstrClient objClient = new mstrClient();
    ModelState.Clear();
    var list = getCountry();
    ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(list, "ID_VALUE", "TEXT_ON_DROPDOWNLIST");
    return View(objClient);
}
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Select a item from the dropdownlist</label>
                        @Html.DropDownList("CountryList", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It Working , Thank u very much SAn

Comment: but one issue, While submitting data it showing error , Like There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ProductList'.

Comment: You need to call again the ViewBag if you return the view because is dynamic and only lasts during current http request. ViewData values will be cleared if redirection occurs.

Comment: OH, you need to name the ViewBag.CountryList like your ID of your property on your class